# How can I install JRE from source?

Tags: java, runtime

I tried installing the latest version of JRE on my computer running ubuntu 20.04. JRE was not installed prior to this.
Here are the steps I followed.

1. headed to https://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp
2. Downloaded the **Linux x64** package, and, got the file named **jre-8u261-linux-x64.tar.gz**.
3. From my terminal I ran the following command; `$sudo cp jre-8u261-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/src` to copy the file to the /local/src directory.
4. Inside the src directory I decompressed the package using`$ sudo tar zxvf jre-8u261-linux-x64.tar.gz` and got the directory **jre1.8.0_261**

No further instructions were given on installation and the JRE doesnt seem to be installed.

Comment: Define “install”. Also define “from source” - you’ve downloaded a tar of the compiled binaries, this seems to have nothing to do with “from source” in the common understanding, which would require compilation. If you’re struggling with this, why not just [install using apt](https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-ubuntu-20-04/) - which is designed to do the heavy lifting (path, alternatives etc) for you?

Comment: What you have there is not the source code.  It is a tar file of the JRE binaries.  You just uncompress it and untar it.   Then start using it.  (You could add the bin directory to the "PATH" but that isn't mandatory ...)  But installing Java on Ubuntu using "apt" is the recommended way to go.

Comment: @StephenC adding to the PATH is one way to go, but to correctly install a version of Java Ubuntu generally goes down the alternatives route. Just adding it to your PATH may make certain things unhappy - which assume the use of alternatives. If it’s just needed for one application then obviously that doesn’t matter - and if you’re just using it for your IDE you don’t even need to go as far as adding it to the PATH.

Comment: *"... you don’t even need to go as far as adding it to the PATH"*.  Indeed!  That is why I said *"You **could** add the bin directory to the "PATH" **but that isn't mandatory** "*.  There are many ways you could install Oracle Java on Ubuntu.  Including doing exactly what the Oracle instructions say and no more.  It depends on what you expect installation to do.

Comment: Thank all of you for the responses. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you needed to unpack it into the usr/lib/ Try to do as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zp10aJqj51M
jdk 8 includes jre, so if you don't want to install open jdk follow the instructions in the video

Comment: Just do not forget that your version of Java is different, most likely 1.8.0.261

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested - no joy. I ended up installing using apt. Thanks a ton for your help.